# Update multiple documents in ES index using spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

Using spring-data-elasticsearch v5.1.0, I want to update all documents in my index to add/overwrite some fields.

This does not work (afaiu it only works for single-document update queries, correct?):

```java
Document document = Document.create().fromJson("\"myobj\":" + jsonAsString + "}");
UpdateQuery updateQuery = UpdateQuery.builder(Query.findAll()).withDocument(document);
operations.updateByQuery(updateQuery, IndexCoordinates.of("my-index");
```

Is the only way transforming my json into a map of params?

```java
String script = "ctx._source.catalog = params.myobj";
Map<String, Object> params = Map.of("myobj", new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonAsString, Map.class));
UpdateQuery updateQuery = UpdateQuery.builder(Query.findAll()).withScriptType(ScriptType.INLINE).withScript(script).withParams(params).build();
operations.updateByQuery(updateQuery, IndexCoordinates.of("my-index");
```